# Waiting for XHR to finish in AngularJS before rendering template

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest, angularjs-scope, wait

When switching Views in AngularJS (from #1 to #2), I am sending two XHR requests to the server. One of them is finished quicker and as soon as it is, the template gets rendered. However, in the template I'm referring to data that comes back from the second request, which at that time is not finished yet.
Is there a way that I can wait for all requests to finish before rendering the template?

Currently I'm simply defining methods in the controller and then at its bottom, executing the XHR requests and assigning the response to $scope variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the $compile directive to render your HTML-Templates dynamically, you could add

```
ng-show="showCtrl"
```

And in your controller preset

```
$scope.showCtrl = false;
```

If you have the standard route provider, wrap your HTML-Template with a DIV e.g.

```
<div style="display:none" or ng-show="showCtrl">
```

If your XHR Request is finished, just take the DIV-Element with attribute and say

```
display:block or 
showCtrl = true; $scope.$apply();
```

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the promise service

Please refer to 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the best way to handler this is to use a **`resolve`** on your router.

If you are using the default Angular router, see the docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider, specifically the `resolve` property of the route definition. It allows you to specify any async calls that will be completed *before* the route changes and the next view is loaded.

If you use angular-ui-router, there is the exact same concept there.

Here is an example of using `resolve` from the angular docs:

```
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
     $routeProvider
         .when('/Book/:bookId', {

               templateUrl: 'book.html',

               controller: 'BookController',

               resolve: {
                 // I will cause a 1 second delay
                 delay: function($q, $timeout) {
                   var delay = $q.defer();
                   $timeout(delay.resolve, 1000);
                 return delay.promise;
               }
         }
     });
 });
```

Obviously they have a fake async call here with a timeout, but as long as your XHR call returns a promise (which will be the case if you use the `$http` service), then your controller can just be injected with `delay` in this case, and use the resolved data straight away.